# Data imported from excel read as float

Tags: python, excel

I am importing data from an excel spreadsheet to generate source code for a website. When doing so, I noticed that some zip codes are being classified as strings while others are floats. All of the data in the spreadsheet is the same format 'xxxx' or 'xxxxx-xxxx' to express zip code. Here is some sample output I ran (printing the zip code followed by the type):

```
35007-9998
<class 'str'>
Athens
<class 'str'>
AL
<class 'str'>
35611.0
<class 'float'>
```

The data is not entered into the spreadsheet as 35611.0, rather 35611. Any ideas on why this may be?

Comment: Because excel automatically identifies numbers for you, regardless of what you want.

Comment: the .0 at the end because it is a float value and excel identifies numbers for you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Is there anything I can do to eliminate this? Even classifying the data as text in excel does not fix the issue

Comment: @TonyM I am using the xlrd import function and using a for loop to iterate through each column -- ex: sheet.cell_value(x,1)

Comment: Since Excel does formating magic in cells that is not always apparent, you might consider exporting from Excel to simple text prior to your import.

Comment: @OP. That should have been your question to begin with. You can do something like `if isinstance(x, float): x = '{:05.0f}'.format(x)`